# JSF: inputText with converter in dataTable Problem

Tags: jsf, datatable, rerender

I build a h:inputText for a cell in h:dataTable with customized converter.
The input text can be converted and the converted text can be displayed if I rerender the whole table.

The problem is, the reredering of the whole table will release the focus of next input box. I try to explain it clearly.

The problem that I have:

1. User input data in a table cell.
2. User press tab key and jump to next input box in the table.
3. Meanwhile the just inputed text will be converted and displayed immediately.
4. But user lost the focus of the next input box because of the rerendering of whole table.

What I want is:

1. User input data in a table cell.
2. User press tab key and jump to next input box in the table.
3. Meanwhile the just inputed text should be converted and displayed immediately.
4. User should not lose the focus of the next input box (maybe use a partial rerendering).

I also try to assign id to every single cell for the partial rerendering, but I don't know how to do this in dataTable.

Anyone has any solution to solve the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just refer the `id` of the output component in `render` attribute of `f:ajax`.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.model}" var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText value="#{item.value}">
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="output" />
        </h:inputText>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText id="output" value="#{item.value}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h:inputText value="#{item.value}">
  <f:ajax event="blur" render="@this" execute="@this"/>
</h:inputText>
```

The execute attribute should trigger the converter. You do not need a separate outputText this way.

Comment: I understood that he is displaying the converted text *somewhere*, but not inside the same component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do want to display the converted text inside the input feld. I use jsf 1.2 not 2.0, so is there any other solution except @this ??

Comment: You could refer to the id of the inputText directly. Simply replace "@this" with the id of the inputText field.